# Загрузить страницу настроек addPreferencesFromResource

Tags: java, android

Как загрузить, layout с настройками (addPreferencesFromResource) в такой конструкции?:

```
public class OrderFragment extends Fragment {

    public OrderFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. **PreferenceFragment** является наследником **Fragment**, то вы можете наследовать свой фрагмент от **PreferenceFragment**, задать в нём разметку методом **addPreferencesFromResource()**, а далее действовать как с обычным фрагментом. Например добавить в экран активити.